# Regex to determine indian mobile number

Tags: php, regex

Please help me improve my Regex to detect Indian Mobile Number. It is not matching all patterns :

```
+91-9883443344
0091-9883443344
+91 -9883443344
+91- 9883443344
+91 -9883443344
0091 - 9883443344

$pattern = "/((([\+?\(91\)\s?]|\-|0|((00|\+)?91))-?)?[7-9]\d{9,11})/s";
```

Comment: This is a great resource for next time you need to build a regex: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:\+|00)91\h*-\h*\d{10}$
```

This works for all your examples. This will match either `+` or `00` at start followed by hyphen with optional spaces on either side of hyphen followed by 10 digits.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG5pA9/1)

Comment: Thanks . You answered well. It Worked!!

Comment: Much cleaner than the one I came up with: `(\(?[0]{0,2}?91\)?\s?-?\s?[7-9]\d{9,11})`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it to this Regex: 
Which I tested on : 
9822010143     +919454333035     +91-9883443344 0091-9883443344  +91 -9883443344 +91- 9883443344 +91 -9883443344  0091 - 9883443344 8892222223

```
$pattern = "((\+?\(?[0]{0,2}?(91|86)?\)?\s?-?\s?[7-9]\d{9,11}))";
```

$comment = preg_replace($pattern, '

Call Us

', $comment);
var_dump($comment);